# How do I use cookies to create a number that increases on the click of a button and stays the same after multiple website visits (HTML / JS)?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, counter

I'm trying to make a basic website that has a text box that will display a counter. The user can click a button to add one to the counter and I'm trying to make it so that the counter can retain its value across multiple distinct visits to the websites. I'm using cookies to solve the retention issue but I'm not sure that's the best solution. As of right now the counter button isn't working at all. I'm very new to HTML and Java. Thank you in advance. Below is my code.

```
<html>
    <head><meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" method="post" name="form1">
    <p>
    <input id="set_Value" name="set_Value" onclick="setValue()" type="button" value="Add 1" />
    </p>
<p>
Counter:<label><input id="bbb" name="bbb" type="text" /> </label>
</p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + '=';
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return '';
}
function setCookie(cname, value) {
if(document.cookie(cname) == null) { 
    document.cookie = cname;
}
        document.cookie = cname + '=' + value + ';' + ';path=/';
    }
    function setValue() {
setCookie(Counter, getValue(Counter)+1);
document.getElementById('bbb').value = getValue(Counter);

    }
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use local storage instead of cookies

Comment: Would local storage maintain the value of counter even after multiple visits?

Comment: yep! until you delete it

Comment: here's a link to a jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/47wnajcu/1/

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know local storage worked like that.